# model comparison when alternatives are not all nested within one another

Tags: generalized-linear-model, model-selection, aic, glmm

I am running a glmm with three fixed effects:

opponent 1 size ("1")
opponent 2 size ("2")
opponent 1 size - opponent 2 size ("diff")

I am unable to run all three variables in the model at once because of the "diff" variable being correlated with the "1" and "2" variables. How, then, do I decide which is the best model, when all the different combinations I can test are not nested within one another? Or can I consider the first two variables to be nested within the third one, since they are both used to calculate "diff"? I have these combinations of variables and their corresponding AICs (variable(s) followed by AIC in parentheses):

variable(s) (AIC):
diff    (223)
1            (231)
2            (262)
1,2          (265)
1,diff       (265)
2,diff       (265)

Answer (score 0):

Run the model with the first two predictors. It is not necessary to include the third, since this is merely a linear combination of the first two.

Comment: But the predictive power of the third variable is the one I (and my reviewers) are most interested in! :)

Comment: Can you leave one of the first predictors out, then?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. The goal is to determine which of those three factors best explains the outcome of a contest.